# Rasa Core - Get Latest Message, Custom Action

Tags: python, machine-learning, spacy, rasa-core

How do I just collect a user response in Rasa Core without extracting an entity. Right now I have been able to hack it by doing the following, but I am wondering if there is a better way?

domain.yml

```
slots:
  slot: animal
    type: categorical
    values:
    - cat
    - dog
```

stories.md

```
*greet
   -utter_greet
*inform{"Animal":"Dog"}
   - utter_hello_fido
*inform
   - do_my_action
```

python code:

```
class MyAction(Action):

    def name(self):
       return 'do_my_action'
    def run(self):
        message = tracker.latest.text
        operate on(message)

    return []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify to ignore entity extraction for certain intents by specifying that in your Rasa domain file (see the [docs](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/domains/#ignoring-entities-for-certain-intents) here):

```
intents:
  - greet:
      use_entities: None
```

This would ignore all extracted entities for the intent `greet`.